# Is it possible to select the partition where you want the hibernation file?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hibernate

I have a PC where I have installed both Windows 7 32-bit and 64-bit. As I don't want to have both system partitions overloaded I've moved the pagination file to the "Data" partition so that both share that file and would like to do that too for the hibernation file.

Is it possible to select the partition you want for the hibernation file? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the respective hiberfil.sys has to be on the same partition where the operating system is installed.

However, if you don't need hibernation you can disable it from an elevated command prompt:

> powercfg -h off

This will turn off hibernation and delete hiberfil.sys

Comment: And this is why: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.11.windowsconfidential.aspx